# Is modification of string literals undefined behaviour according to the C89 standard?

Tags: c

I believe that in C99, modification of string literals is undefined behaviour. I don't have a copy of that standard but I do have a draft of C1X (n1570) which states in 6.4.5 paragraph 7:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

I have found a Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981828/why-doesnt-the-compiler-detect-and-produce-errors-when-attempting-to-modify-cha) that touches on this topic and contains the following comment from Jonathan Leffler:

> Originally, the C89 (C90) standard did not outlaw modifying literals because there was too much code written before the standard that would be broken by it.

But I have also seen lots of discussion of the *type* of string literals and the fact that they are `char[N]` and not `const char[N]`. I gather that this decision was taken so that the large body of existing code would not break.

Can anyone give me a definitive answer. Is string literal modification UB in C89?

Comment: What? As far as I know, string literals are `const char *`...

Comment: @H2CO3: Not in C.

Comment: I remember seeing a program for the venerable [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) that would merge identical strings in object code to make it smaller, so modifying string literals was a bad idea even before C89.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, they are non-modifiable in C89.

> (C90, 6.1.4) "If the program attempts to modify a string literal of either form, the behavior is undefined"

Even in K&R 2nd edition, there are quotes regarding the immutability of string literals.

> (K&R2, 5.5) "the result is undefined if you try to modify the string contents"
>
> (K&R2, Appendix C) "Strings are no longer modifiable, and so may be placed in read-only memory"

In the ANSI C89 Rationale, there is an explanation of why it is non-modifiable:

> (ANSI C89 Rationale, 3.1.4) "String literals are specified to be unmodifiable.  This specification allows implementations to share copies of strings with identical text, to place string literals in read-only memory, and perform certain optimizations."