# Access Violation, memset

Tags: c, access-violation

The following code throws an access violation at line L2 at runtime, which happens during the 2nd call to setword.

Q> Where am I going wrong in L2, and why is there no problem with the 1st memset at line L1?

Note: I have tried to isolate the problem area from a larger code, hope this provides enough info.

```
void setword( char ** word )
{
    if ( *word == NULL )
    {
       *word = (char *)malloc(30);
        memset( *word, '\0', 30 ); //L1: OK 
    }
    else
    {   
        memset( *word, '\0', 30 );//L2: Access violation
    }

    *word = "Hello";
    //*word shall be freed when operations are complete.
}
int main()
{
    char * word = NULL;

    setword( &word );  //Call 1: OK
    printf( "%s\n", word );

    setword( &word );  //Call 2: NOK!
    printf( "%s\n", word );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
*word = (char *)malloc(30);
[...]
*word = "Hello";
```

The second assignment produces a memory leak (you've lost the pointer that malloc returned), and makes `word` point to potentially read-only memory - any write access to it will lead to undefined behavior.

(See for example this question: [Is modification of string literals undefined behaviour according to the C89 standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001202/is-modification-of-string-literals-undefined-behaviour-according-to-the-c89-stan?rq=1) - in your case, `"Hello"` is a string literal. You make `word` point to that with the second assignment. So you can't modify the data that `word` points to afterwards.)

Use `strcpy` to copy `"hello"` to your dynamically allocated buffer.

Comment: I would just like to add that "Hello" is the part of the program static data and probably really IS read-only memory.  OP is lucky because if it wasn't he'll overwrite what's next there...

Comment: Thanks a lot Mat. In my original code I was not assiging something to *word, I was actually filling it up using **word = some_char. However, I DID do some pointer arithmetic with *word, on which I lost the original *word, leading to all hell being let lose, as you have pointed out!

Answer (score 0):

you should know that after `*word = "Hello"`, the value of `*word` is constant region, you can change the content of this region.