# How to copy a string in C

Tags: c, string

if I have the function scopy that copies a C String from src to dest

```
char * scopy(char *dest, char *src) {
    char* r = dest;
    while (*src != '\0') {
        *dest = *src;
        dest++;
        src++;
    }
    *dest = *src;
    return r;
}
```

Why does this function work when called on 2 String initialized like this
char a[6] = "abbbb" and
char b[4] = "dcd"
but doesn't work on Strings initialized like this
char * a = "abbbb" and
char * b = "dcd"

Comment: arrays and pointers are different beasts. You might like to read the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/), especially sections 4, 5, and 6.

Answer (score 1):

This function invokes undefined behavior when used like that because it tries to [modify a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001202/is-modification-of-string-literals-undefined-behaviour-according-to-the-c89-stan), so you can't say it works in either case.

The fact that it appears to work on the `char[]` is a coincidence -- an unfortunate one, because it gives the wrong impression.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, variable `ptr` is pointing to a read-only memory section, which contains `"xyz\0"`. You can change the variable itself, but you can't change the contents of the memory it is pointing to...

```
char* ptr = "xyz";
```

---

In the code below, variable `arr` is pointing to a read/write memory section, which contains `"xyz\0"`. You can't change the variable itself, but you can change the contents of the memory it is pointing to...

```
char arr[] = "xyz";
```

---

The above should help you to understand why you are getting a segmentation fault in the first case...

Having said that, you have yet another problem in your code - if the string pointed by `src` is longer than the string pointed by `dest`, then `*dest = *src` will most likely cause a segmentation fault:

```
while (*src != '\0')
{
    *dest = *src;
    dest++;
    src++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

char*a = "abbbb" is called a string literal, which iirc behaves differently than a char[] in c. Specifically, I do not believe you can modify the individual characters for a string literal.

Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string) for more information between the two constructors