# What is the error in my c code?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IsLowerCase(c) (((c)>='a') && ((c)<='z'))
#define ToUpperCase(s) (IsLowerCase(s)? (s)-'a' + 'A': (s))

int main(void){

    char *string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    while(*string != '\0'){
        *string = ToUpperCase(*string);
        ++string;
    }

}
```

warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Comment: it's warning..not error

Comment: You're trying to modify a string constant, which isn't allowed.  Use an array instead.

Comment: "error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `char *string` should be `const char *string` (but it is immutable); or better `char string[] = ...`. and then declare another variable `char *s = string;`, and loop and step `s` instead of `string`

Comment: In this case, casting `const char*` to `char*` and modifying the array later on results in UB.

Comment: What’s long form for UB?

Comment: Undefined behaviour - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766731/what-exactly-do-ib-and-ub-mean

Answer (score 0):

`char *string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` is a literal (cannot be modified), and if you try to modify it, you will be getting [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001202/is-modification-of-string-literals-undefined-behaviour-according-to-the-c89-stan). If you want a modifiable string, allocate memory or use a `char[]` array.

This will do the trick `char string[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`. Now it should work with the rest of your code.

You can get more information on your issue in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal).

Comment: It is undefined behavior regardless of operating system, compiler, or hardware because the C Standard says so. It will cause a crash with most compiler-hardware combinations because the compiler will put the string in a read-only memory segment.

Answer (score 0):

the problem started here

```
char *string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

You declared "string" as pointer to character type but initialized it with "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ( this is const string and  will be invalid )  .
In order to correct it you need to do two things.

1. declare a variable ,say str, of type string i.e. "string str;"
   and the initialize it with a string , i.e

   ```
   "string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   ```
2. declare your pointer "string" with type string * ,i.e string *string.

   and intialize it with the address of str, i.e

   ```
   string *string = &str;
   ```

   so your  final code will took like this

   ```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include<string.h> //to use the string data type
   #define IsLowerCase(c) (((c)>='a') && ((c)<='z'))
   #define ToUpperCase(s) (IsLowerCase(s)? (s)-'a' + 'A': (s))

   int main(void){
   string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   string  *string = &str;
   while(*string != '\0'){
   *string = ToUpperCase(*string);
   ++string;
   }

   }
   ```