# How to copy memory between two void pointers through a macro?

Tags: c, memory, macros

So I am trying to write my own macro version of a memory copy implementation, yet for some reason it's exiting with non zero status for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BTools_WRITE(dest, src, n) for (size_t i = 0;i<n;i++) { \
                *(unsigned char*)(dest++) = *(unsigned char*)(src++); \
}

int main(void) {
  char* f = "Hello sir!";
  char* u = "4444";
  void* fptr = f;
  void* uptr = u;
  int g = 4;
  BTools_WRITE(fptr, uptr, g);
  printf("%s\n", f);
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried changing the for loop to while loop, or putting a do-while loop around the whole macro, it always returns with non-zero status. How can I fix this? Can this be done with just a macro?

Comment: Any reason not using memcpy?

Comment: modifying a string literal is undefined behavior

Comment: memcpy is bound to be insanely optimized.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10001202/694576 (a bit general to serve as a "duplicate to"?)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to write to the const data of your program.  Try this;

```
char f[] = "Hello sir!";
```