# What the memory difference between char *array and char array[]?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

When I execute the next code

```
int main()
{
    char tmp[] = "hello";
    printf("%lp, %lp\n", tmp, &tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

I had got the same addresses. But for the next code, they will be different

```
int main()
{
    char *tmp = "hello";
    printf("%lp, %lp\n", tmp, &tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Could you explain the memory differences between those examples?

Comment: `char tmp[] = "hello"` is an array of 6 characters initialized to `"hello\0"` (it has automatic storage duration and resides within the program stack). `char *tmp = "hello";` is a pointer initialized with the address for the  String Literal `"hello\0"` that resides in readonly memory (generally within the `.rodata` section of the executable). (readonly on all but a few non-standard implementations) An array is converted to a pointer to its first element on access.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Re "*readonly on all but a few non-standard implementations*", I find it doubtful that C requires a machine to have virtual memory to have a standard implementation. Once should always consider the memory to be read-only, but I challenge the claim that the memory has to be read-only for the implementation to be standard.

Comment: @ikegami I concede that point. The standard doesn't require a conforming implementation to create string literals in read only memory. The point I was making is most do.

Comment: At very least the C standard states modifying string literals is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001202/is-modification-of-string-literals-undefined-behaviour-according-to-the-c89-stan).

Comment: While legal in C you shouldn't assign string literals to non-const `char` pointers, always do `char const* ptr = "some literal";` – otherwise you almost certainly *will* run into modifying the literal at some point in the future, which is UB, as stated above. Being able to assign immutable literals to `char*` pointers is a legacy from the very first days of C where `const` did not yet exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char tmp[] = "hello";` is an array of 6 characters initialized to `"hello\0"` (it has automatic storage duration and resides within the program stack).

`char *tmp = "hello";` is a pointer to `char` initialized with the address for the  string literal `"hello\0"` that resides in readonly memory (generally within the `.rodata` section of the executable, readonly on all but a few implementations).

When you have `char tmp[] = "hello";`, as stated above, on access the array is converted to a pointer to the first element of `tmp`. It has type `char *`. When you take the address of `tmp` (e.g. `&tmp`) it will resolve to the same address, but has a completely different type. It will be a *pointer-to-array-of* `char[6]`. The formal type is `char (*)[6]`. And since **type controls pointer arithmetic**, iterating with the different types will produce different offsets when you advance the pointer. Advancing `tmp` will advance to the next `char`. Advancing with the address of `tmp` will advance to the beginning of the next 6-character array.

When you have `char *tmp = "hello";` you have a pointer to `char`. When you take the address, the result is *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char`. The formal type is `char **` reflecting the two levels of indirection. Advancing `tmp` advances to the next `char`. Advancing with the address of `tmp` advances to the next pointer.

Comment: `char tmp[]`: Advance `tmp` is unlucky wording, as arrays cannot be incremented (like `++tmp`). I wouldn't describe *'string literal `"hello\0"`'* as that would imply a literal with *two* trailing null characters.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the pointer that results from access. Obviously you cannot iterate with the array itself. The intent being `char *p = tmp;` or `char (*p)[6] = &tmp;` in the array case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: So to clear up my mind, (supposing tmp1 and tmp2 in the order on your answer), from an Assembly point of view `tmp1 == &tmp1`, and `tmp2 != &tmp2`. `tmp1` and `&tmp1` are exactly the same except in C they have different types (both the same stack address); `tmp2` is the pointer to the 1st string char (which might be on the stack or on read-only data or something), and `&tmp2` is a pointer to `tmp2`, which in this case will be a stack address (because tmp2 is a local variable - or at least supposing it is). And these things are the same passed to a function as arguments. Is this correct?

Comment: @DADi590 - you are dead-on. That is the exact case. `tmp1` and `&tmp1` resolve to the same address  `tmp2` is a **pointer to** the 1st char in the string, and `&tmp2` is the **address of that pointer**, not the address of the 1st character in the string. In other words, the address for the 1st character in the string is the **address pointed to** (e.g. held-by) `tmp2`, `&tmp2` is where that address is stored in memory.

Answer (score 3):

```
char a[] = "hello";
```

and

```
char *a = "hello";
```

Get stored in different places.

### char a[] = "hello"

In this case, `a` becomes an array(stored in the stack) of 6 characters initialized to "hello\0". It is the same as:

```
char a[6];
a[0] = 'h';
a[1] = 'e';
a[2] = 'l';
a[3] = 'l';
a[4] = 'o';
a[5] = '\0';
```

### char *a = "hello"

Inspect the assembly(this is not all the assembly, only the important part):

```
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "hello" ////Look at this part
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    $.LC0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

See

```
.section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "hello"
```

This is where the string is stored. `char a[]` is stored in the stack while `char *a` is stored wherever the compiler likes. Generally in rodata.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
char tmp[] = "hello";
```

you are setting aside an *array* of `char` large enough to store the string `"hello"` and copying the contents of the string to that array, such that you get this in memory:

```
     +–––+
tmp: |'h'| tmp[0]
     +–––+
     |'e'| tmp[1]
     +–––+
     |'l'| tmp[2]
     +–––+
     |'l'| tmp[3]
     +–––+
     |'o'| tmp[4]
     +–––+
     | 0 | tmp[5]
     +–––+
```

There is no `tmp` object separate from the array elements themselves, so the address of the array (`tmp`) is the same as the address of its first element (`tmp[0]`).

With

```
char *tmp = "hello";
```

you are creating a *pointer* to `char` and initializing it with the *address* of the first character in the *string literal* `"hello"`, such that you get this in memory:

```
     +–––+       +–––+
tmp: |   | ––––> |'h'| tmp[0]
     +–––+       +–––+
                 |'e'| tmp[1]
                 +–––+
                 |'l'| tmp[2]
                 +–––+
                 |'l'| tmp[3]
                 +–––+
                 |'o'| tmp[4]
                 +–––+
                 | 0 | tmp[5]
                 +–––+
```

In this case `tmp` *is* a separate object from the array elements, so the address of `tmp` is different from the address of `tmp[0]`.