# trying copy character from pointer to string

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse string using pointer ([ref source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-reverse-a-string-using-pointers/)). in function

```
string_reverse
```

Bus Error happened at this line when copying character from char pointer `end` to `start` char pointer  :

```
 *start = *end;
```

I tried LLDB in VS code. [image: Screen shot attached].

Can some one explain why there is **bus error** happened at below line?

```
*start = *end
```

Full code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void string_reverse(char* str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    char temp;
    char *end = str;
    char *start = str;

    /* Move end pointer to the last character */
    for (int j = 0; j < len-1; j++)
    {
        end++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< len/2;i++ )
    {
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;

        /* update pointer positions */
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    
}


int main( void ) 
{

    char *str = "test string";
    
    printf("Original string is %s\n", str);
    string_reverse(str);
    printf("Reverse string is %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Actual result: Bus Error happened at line

```
*start = *end;
```

Expected output:

```
Reverse string is gnirts tset
```

Comment: Try `char *str = "test string";` --> `char str[] = "test string";` as attempting to reverse a _string literal_ is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks @chux - Reinstate Monica. It has worked. I got expected output. But I am still not clear why  undefined behavior of char pointer initialized to string literals

Comment: Your code attempted to modify a _string literal_, no?  That is UB since [C89 and K&R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10001202/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because

```
char * str = "...";
```

mean you have a pointer to a string literal. It's a constant string that you can not modify.
When you change it to

```
char str[] = "...";
```

as [chux-reinstate-monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) mentioned, str will be char array with the length of your string, and you can modify it without any error.