# Why does the second print not show anything

Tags: c

I am beginner in C and have the following code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){
    char *s1="abcd";
    char s2[30]="abcd";
    if(strcmp(s1,s2)){
        printf("sirurile sunt identice\n");
    }else printf("sirurile sunt diferite\n");
    strcpy(s2,s1);
    printf("%s\n",s1);
    strcpy(s1,s2);
    printf("%s\n",s2);
    return 0; 
}
```

I'm trying to understand why the output doesn't take into consideration the second print and shows only the first 'abcd'.Output is : sirurile sunt diferite
abcd

I expected the abcd to be printed twice since the strings seem to be copied one on another

Comment: `strcpy(s1,s2);` invokes *undefined behavior* - you cannot write to a string literal

Answer (score 5):

String literals are often stored in a read-only data section of the process.
In your program s1 points to that read-only area.
That's why you are getting seg fault when trying to change it with strcpy.

For a detailed explanation, read this post [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Answer (score 0):

```
char * s1 = "abcd";
```

means you have pointer to string literal. you can not modify. [That is UB since C89 and K&R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001202/is-modification-of-string-literals-undefined-behaviour-according-to-the-c89-stan)

When you change it to

```
char s1[]="abcd";
```

`s1` will be char array with the length of your string, and you can modify it without any error.

Modified code snippet based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(void){
    char s1[]="abcd";
    char s2[30]="abcd";
    if(strcmp(s1,s2)){
        printf("sirurile sunt identice\n");
    }else printf("sirurile sunt diferite\n");
    strcpy(s2,s1);
    printf("%s\n",s1);
    strcpy(s1,s2);
    printf("%s\n",s2);
    return 0; 
}
```

## Output:

```
sirurile sunt diferite
abcd
abcd
```

you can find the output of above code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xeW1_qmZ3)